# How to integrate contact form 7 with woocommerce .?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I am just a beginner and don't know alot about coding. I made a conditional order form with the help of contact form 7 wordpress plugin.

I am trying to find a plugin or any way where form shows on woocommerce product page without picture and tabs OR after filling the contact form 7, Checkout will be done through woocommerce.

Reason for checkout through woocommerce is becuause of the order history and order email of the user.
Any idea how to do that .?

so far i have tried to put the below code but nothing happens and its just change the url to id like this "#wpcf7-f597-p77-o1".

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
location = 'http://www.website.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=ID';}, false );
```

Edit:

Add a code in contact form 7 Additional Settings area nothing happens instead it just change the url

[image]

[image]

Secondly the product shows like this

I want only to show form

[image]

Comment: which kind of form you want to use because woocomerce has almost all the fields

Comment: it would be a conditional logic form with calculated fields. When the user select options. total amount appear on the form. What i want is insTEAD OF product the form show without images and other options go checkout through woocommerce.

Comment: share your code and screen shot so can get better idea

Comment: shared. I hope you understand this